# What Linux fits on a floppy disk?

Tags: linux, bootable-media, floppy

Which Linux distributions fit on a 1.44 MB bootable floppy disk?

Where can the .img image files be downloaded?

Answer (score 13):

Check out the [Small Linux site by Ben Gross](http://bengross.com/smallunix.html).  It includes several very minimal linux distros that fit on a floppy.  Quoted from his site:

> 1. [tomsrtbt](http://www.toms.net/rb/) is Tom's bootable linux-based distribution that will fit on a floppy.  This is one of the most popular.
> 2. [Recovery Is Possible](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/) (RIP) is a floppy boot/rescue/backup system.
> 3. [Coyote Linux](http://www.coyotelinux.com/) is a single floppy distribution of Linux that is derived from the Linux Router Project (LRP).
> 4. [FREESCO](http://www.freesco.info/) (FREE ciSCO).  Designed to be used as a router.
> 5. [Serial Terminal Linux](http://www.eskimo.com/~johnnyb/computers/stl/) allows you to use an old laptop as a serial console.
> 6. [muLinux](http://sunsite.dk/mulinux/) is a full-configurable, minimalistic, almost complete, application-centric tiny distribution of Linux (2.0.36
>      modular kernel) made in Italy. muLinux resides on a single 1722K
>      floppy, but floppy add-ons are provided.
> 7. [NanoBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/nanobsd/) is the successor to PicoBSD designed to run on embedded or appliance platforms.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.linuxlinks.com/Distributions/Floppy/

Comment: No longer works

Answer (score 3):

[Basic Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/distributions/baslinux/) is based on an old Slackware distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds good: http://www.toms.net/rb/

<strike>EDIT: Seems the download links are actually unavailable.</strike>
It is available [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/system/recovery/). Used to be an invaluable resource, but these days most people just use [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/)

This is a two floppy distribution which sounds good:
http://blueflops.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, I think Puppy Linux or Damn Small Linux will fit on a floppy.

Comment: Strictly speaking, these two distros don't fit on a floppy, but you can create a boot floppy which will provide the ability to boot from CD, file or USB.