# Temporary operating system from floppy disk

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios

I run Windows on my computer (which has a floppy disk drive and usb ports), and I want to try out a linux operating system.  If I modify the BIOS to load from the floppy or usb first which contains the os, is it possible to revert back to Windows safely, and would any files be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [What Linux fits on a floppy](https://superuser.com/q/130457/52492) - but a bootable USB device is a better idea.

You can also run Linux as an application within Windows (an example is [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) which is based on an old Ubuntu).

None of these disrupt Windows.

Comment: Would a larger linux that is booted from a USB also not disrupt Windows?

Comment: As long as you dont mess with the params like partitions and file system of the drive that Windows is installed on, you're ok.. No boot process alters the partitions, exist boot records or file systems.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't mess with the filesystem of your primary OS system drive while using your alternative OS, yes you'll be fine, no files get auto deleted.

I'm curious why on earth you are using a floppy for this and what OS even fits on a floppy... but hey, each to his own :)

Comment: I could use a flash drive also, it's just from what I've heard floppies work best.  Now that I think about it, it does sound pretty dumb to attempt and hold an os.

Comment: I'd say that floppy works the worst haha. The only reason to load one up is novelty :)

Comment: If its an older system, and you want to flash the bios... that might almost make sense

Comment: @zchbrntmr Floppy drive = 500 kb/s, USB 2.0 drive = 480 Mb/s. That's **~1000** times faster. I vote flash drive...